# how to subprocess call and catching success

Tags: python, subprocess

Upon reading up on subprocess module (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)
it is not clear to me if every word needs to be written in quotes separately or can be grouped somehow

For eg:

```
cmd -vvv <positional arg> <keyword arg> <keyword arg>
```

which is correct way of calling subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(['command', '-vvv', '<positional arg>', '<keyword arg>', '<keyword arg>'])
subprocess.call(['command', '-vvv', '<positional arg>', '<keyword arg> <keyword arg>'])
subprocess.call(['command', '-vvv', '<positional arg> <keyword arg> <keyword arg>'])
```

Also how to catch if it was processed correctly. is this the right way:

```
a = subprocess.call(...from above...)
if a == 0:
    success
else:
    fail
```

this does not seem correct, but I saw it return '0' when its success, so thought of above solution.

Comment: i dont think subprocess.call takes a list, but a string instead. so just `subprocess.call("cmd -vvv <positional arg> <keyword arg> <keyword arg>")`

Comment: @tmthyjames, `call` takes a list or a string. Imho, using a list is usually the better way to use `call`.

Comment: @BiRico Ahh. didnt know that. good to know.

Answer (score 3):

The first is the right way to do it:

```
subprocess.call(['command', '-vvv', '<positional arg>', '<keyword arg>', '<keyword arg>'])
```

Better use `subprocess.check_call()` instead of checking for failure yourself:

> Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete.  If
>   the exit code was zero then return, otherwise raise
>   CalledProcessError.  The CalledProcessError object will have the
>   return code in the returncode attribute.

If you also need the output from the process, use `subprocess.check_output()`.